# How to add Caption with image(Object like Bitmap)while posting with Instagram using android

Tags: android, android-intent

I got the some code how to `share image with instagram`. its done see my code bellow
But i want to add caption.
i have added code for `share text with image` but its not working. i want to send bitmap object instead of URI with function parameter,how can i add it.

See my code bellow.

```
public void shareInstagram(Uri uri) // instead of uri i want to put bitmap object
 {

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*"); // set mime type 
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri); // instead of uri i want ot add bitmap image 
    shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sample subject");
    //shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sample text");
    //shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Sample title");
    startActivity(shareIntent);
   }
```

Please help me.. Friends

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to pass bitmaps from one Intent to another. It is better to pass a URI and then Picasso to place it in an ImageView as explained on http://square.github.io/picasso/